# Get focus on input angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus

I'm tring to create a focus directive when i open a page with inside a form in the first input text filed.This is the directive

```
app.directive("getFocus", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(scope, element){
            console.log("focus!");
            element.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

and in my html input

```
<input id="ss" data-ng-model="item.value" type="text" data-ng-class="{'get-focus': $first}">
<input id="tt" type="text" data-ng-model="item.value" data-ng-class="{'get-focus': $first}">
```

i use `ng-class` because is a dynamic form creating cycling a json and i don't know which input is created for first. The directive seems not working. Infact, the console.log not appears in the console.. Something's wrong?

Comment: class directives will not work with `ng-class`. they can be used only with the html class attribute.

Comment: even if i use  restrict: 'AC'?

Comment: Yes. In the above case `getFocus` directive will be added based on a condition. We need to re-compile the node after the class is added to get it work

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like that and I end up with this directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('autofocusIf', function($timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    autofocusIf: '&'
  },
  link: function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.$watch('autofocusIf', function(shouldFocus) {
      if (shouldFocus()) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $element[0].focus();
        });
      } else {
        $timeout(function() {
          $element[0].blur();
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
})
```

and then in html

```
<div ng-repeat="repeat in repeats">
  <input type="text" autofocus-if="$first" ng-model="myModel" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you ahve your input inside `ng-repeat` can you make a plunker?

Comment: Ok I'm going to.. Is it a problem if I'm using uikit?

Comment: I don't think so, although I've made a working plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/ohJ62hl0rtNb1NNus9F6?p=preview

Comment: i think i found the problem..or maybe not..you have set the ng-model as input.. in my case i have another ng-model.. see my edit

Comment: is something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0fyixdoAOmnYVilnFrO?p=preview and here not works

Comment: That plunker works for me, I don't think the ng-model is problem here

Comment: well..this is strange :(